# How to change "capacityIncrement" value post initialization in Vector?

Tags: java, vector, frameworks, size, capacity

In vector by default `initialCapacity` is set at `10` and `capacityIncrement` is also set at `10`.

Thus if we do -

```
Vector<String> vector = new Vector<>();
```

we have `initialCapacity` and `capacityIncrement` both set at `10`.

However, we have the flexibility to set our own values.

For example, if we do -

```
Vector<String> vector = new Vector<>(5,5);
```

we have `initialCapacity` and `capacityIncrement` both set at `5`.

Now, post initialization, we have the methods -

`void setSize(int size)`
`void ensureCapacity(int capacity)`
`void trimToSize()`

to change both `size` and `capacity` as per our needs.

But, how can we change the `capacityIncrement` value post initialization as per our need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using reflect.Field as below:

```
public static void main (String[] args){
    Vector<String> vector = new Vector<>(5, 5);
    System.out.println(getMyCapacityIncrement(vector));
    setMyCapacityIncrement(vector, 9);
    System.out.println(getMyCapacityIncrement(vector));
}
private static void setMyCapacityIncrement(Vector<String> myVector, int capacityIncrement){
    try {
        Field field = myVector.getClass().getDeclaredField("capacityIncrement");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set(myVector, capacityIncrement);
        field.setAccessible(false);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static int getMyCapacityIncrement(Vector<String> myVector) {
    try {
        Field field = myVector.getClass().getDeclaredField("capacityIncrement");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        return field.getInt(myVector);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting warning - "WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred", `capacityIncrement` value remains unchanged.

Comment: it is normal that we have:
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
because the access normally is not authorized on the other hand the value is modified

Comment: I added a method (getMyCapacityIncrement) to check the value, so that you are sure

Comment: In Java 17, that warning will turn into an exception.   See https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/a-peek-into-java-17-continuing-the-drive-to-encapsulate-the-java-runtime-internals

Comment: Ah, ok thnx for my tests i had use Java 11 ... thnx :)

Comment: Yea ... well ... it was a bad idea anyway, because you make the OP's program dependent on undocumented Java internals that may may change from version to version, vendor to vendor, etc.

Comment: Thank you, can you please refer me a good tutorial video on reflection?

Comment: I'm sorry i haven't, but i suggest to look at this link ;)
https://jenkov.com/tutorials/java-reflection/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to change the capacity increment after creation?

If you know the (approximate) size of the resulting `List`, you can create it with a suitable capacity, and the default increment is tuned to be good, see [ArrayList Efficiency and size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6267354/2541560).

The reason a method to change the increment doesn't exist in `ArrayList` is because it's unnecessary. That kind of micro tuning is not required (or would be achievable with `ensureCapacity()` anyway), so it makes the API cleaner not to have it.

Comment: First of all - the question is regarding `Vector`, not `ArrayList`. Secondly, `EnsureCapacity` changes `capacity`, not `capacityIncrement`

Comment: The point remains. You can't change it and you don't need to.